# Output of voltage supply drops to about 1V from 5V

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator, short-circuit

I have fabricated a PCB board. It consists of the following circuitry:

9V - 78L05C - (a circuit consisting of resistors, opamps, comparators, analog multiplexers).

I have attached the pictures of circuit from LTSpice, eagle. I have also attached pictures of board layout in eagle and that of actual board (with voltage generation/regulation part magnified)[image: LTSpice schematic, VDD is the output of 78L05], [image: t1_t2 block] [image: Eagle schematic], [image: Eagle layout], [image: Full PCB board], [image: PCB power generation magnified]

When I power the circuit using 9V battery, I see 0.92V at the output of 78L05C regulator instead of 5V. 78L05C has maximum current output of 100 mA. The current measured at the output of 78L05C using multimeter is about 120 mA and it's getting very hot (I believe it's being of this huge current).

I doubted there is a short somewhere in the following circuit. I measured the resistance using multimeter between the output of regulator and the ground pin. I measure 0.585, 1.83, 3.3 when the range is set to 2k, 20k, 200k in the multimeter respectively. So it's not a short! The minimum resistance from above is 0.585k which is high compared to a short.

Here are my two doubts if someone could explain:
1. The resistance measurement clearly shows there is no short between the output of regulator and the ground, then why there is so huge current drawn from the regulator, why is it's voltage about 1V instead of 5V? I have simulated the circuit in spice using an ideal voltage source of 5V, my circuit draws only about 3-4 mA.
2. (Minor) Why is the multimeter showing different readings when set in different ranges? Which one is correct resistance? What are the guidelines to be followed in future?

Thanks in advance for your answers. Awaiting for them...

UPDATE:

I found the problem in my circuit. The part U21 has been reverse soldered i.e., it's GND and VDD pins are interchanged resulting in short inside it. I corrected it and I'm now seeing 4.92V at the output of 78L05. Is this OK or am I supposed to see between 4.95 and 5V?
I thank you all for taking time to answer my doubt and also other suggestions/comments that you have made. I will keep all of them in my mind. It's been really helpful so far :)

Comment: Are you going to share the circuit?

Comment: A resistance measurement across semiconductor devices in-circuit is virtually meaningless unless all you're looking for is a dead short. None of your readings is 'correct'.

Comment: Added pictures of circuit and board

Comment: 4.92V from a 78L05 is not at all unusual.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly possible that you have something on the board that is hooked up wrong and is shorting your +5V rail to GND through a diode junction inside of a chip. At some 100mA this is the type of current that could forward bias that junction resulting in the approximately 0.9V you see on the shorted rail.

One debugging technique is to start opening up various connections or removing chips one by one to find the one that is sucking down the 5V rail.

Note a common issue is chips that have corner VDD and GND connections that may be soldered in 180 degrees out of phase.

Comment: Thanks Mike for taking time to answer my doubt :) As you can see from the picture above all the components are SMD. How do you think I should go ahead in removing them? If you could suggest some ideas. I visually inspected the board I find that all the components are properly hooked.

Answer (score 1):

Start isolating the blocks of your circuit. First, let the supply and regulator stuff unconnected from your load and measure it's voltage. If it is right, connect a dummy load (a 50 ohm resistor - at 5V it shoud "consume" 100mA) and measure again, and so on...

> 78L05C has maximum current output of 100 mA. The current measured at the output of 78L05C using multimeter is about 120 mA

Something is requiring more current than it is capable of supply. This might be the drop cause.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my doubt :) As you can see from the picture above all the components are SMD. How do you think I should go ahead in removing them one by one? If you could suggest some ideas.

Comment: Well, you should have populated the board one by one (doing some testing after each step), or at least in multiple steps. Then you'd be in the position to know which part causes the trouble (the last few components added).
At this point I'd probably take a heat gun, and start removing the ICs - either all of them in one go, or in a few steps (as it seems practical), until the problem goes away.

Comment: Dear Laszlo, I only did the PCB design; manufacturing and assembling is not done by me. I have absolutely no experience in that. So I got the finished board from a PCB company. I don't have option to finish the boards in parts.

Comment: Are you sure your power supply circuit can power all these components??

I didn't check the datasheets. There's a lot of ICs. My impression is that this circuit needs more than 100mA to operate.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a polarized cap that is in backwards. Usually with power removed, everything will measure like there is no short and around what you'd expect, but when power is applied, it will immediately looks like a short.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my doubt :)I think by backwards, you meant reverse connection. I see that all the electrolytic caps (used at the input and output of 78L05C) are properly hooked (the white line to the positive terminal)

Answer (score 0):

This technique is hard work, but does work.

- Find a really good multimeter that has a 200mv range.
- Connect the +ve probe to your regulator output
- Measure the voltage drop along each trace leaving the regulator. The trace with high current will show a steady increase in voltage as you probe along it. Once you pass the point where the "short" is, the voltage drop will level out - you have passed the problem node.

You can also use a low-voltage power supply that doesn't mind shorts and can deliver an amp or so into a dead short - remove your regulator, and connect the supply to the regulator output.

Another thought - whatever is hogging the current is probably getting very hot...

I've used this technique regularly to track down imperfect etching on PCBs. If you are lucky, the high current will blow the imperfection anyway!

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my doubt :) I have a good multimeter with 200mV range. The output of regulator (which is VDD/+5V in my circuit) is fed to resistors and other ICs (opamp/mux/comparator). I measured the current across the resistors connected immediately to VDD. None of them is significant. Total of those is < 100 uA. I cannot measure the part that goes into the ICs. But the total current measured across VDD pin (of any part) and gnd pin is approx 116 mA and only 78L05C is getting hot and nothing else. From this info how should I proceed? Should I remove 78L05C and try?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are measuring? Current cannot be measured "across" a resistor or part; you can measure the current flowing through a resistor or into a part...

Comment: Thanks kiwiron for pointing that out. I'm sorry for the delay. I just googled and understood that. So far I have been measuring current by putting the probes on the two ends (ie., in parallel while it has to be in series) of the part. May I know, how do I measure current across a trace on PCB? Anyways, I found the problem in my circuit. Please read my update above. Thanks again for your time :)